# Numpy array 15min values - hourly mean values

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following situation:

A numpy array

```
x = np.array([12,3,34,5...,])
```

where every entry corresponds to a simulation result (time-step 15min).

Now I need the mean hourly value (mean value of first 4 elements, then next 4, etc.) stored in a new numpy array. Is there a very simple method to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question. Can you give some examples? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To handle arrays whose size may not be a multiple of 4, 
copy `x` into a new array, `tmp`, whose size is a multiple of 4:

```
tmp = np.full((((x.size-1) // 4)+1)*4, dtype=float, fill_value=np.nan)
tmp[:x.size] = x
```

Empty values are represented by `nan`. Then you can reshape and use `nanmean` to compute the mean for each row. `np.nanmean` is like `np.mean` except that it ignores `nan`s:

---

```
x = np.array([12,3,34,5,1])
tmp = np.full((((x.size-1) // 4)+1)*4, dtype=float, fill_value=np.nan)
tmp[:x.size] = x
tmp = tmp.reshape(-1, 4)
print(np.nanmean(tmp, axis=1))
```

prints

```
[ 13.5   1. ]
```

---

If you have [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) installed, then you could build a timeseries and group by a time interval:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x = np.array([12,3,34,5,1])
s = pd.Series(x, index=pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=x.size, freq='15T'))
result = s.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1H')).mean()
print(result)
```

yields

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00    13.5
2000-01-01 01:00:00     1.0
Freq: H, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

```
N = 4
mod_ = x.size % N
x1 = np.pad(x.astype(float), (0, (mod_ > 0) * (N - mod_)), 'constant', constant_values=(np.nan,))
x2 = np.reshape(x1, (int(x1.size/4), 4))
x3 = np.nanmean(x2, axis=1)
print(x3)
```

Comment: What if len(x) % 4 != 0 ?

Comment: @OphirCarmi Thank you very much! When i try this approach i get the error message "ValueError: (0, -190) cannot contain negative values" --> the array contains 194 values, the first one is negativ, the rest positiv

Comment: I added parenthesis around `N - mod_`. The error you got is on the `x1 = ...` line. It's not concerning the values of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

your input:

```
In [11]: x = np.array([12, 3, 34, 5, 1, 2, 3])
```

taking every 4 elements in b

```
In [12]: b = [x[n:n+4] for n in range(0, len(x), 4)]
```

create new empty list to append results

```
In [13]: l = []

In [14]: for i in b:
   ....:     l.append(np.mean(i))
   ....:     

In [15]: l
Out[15]: [13.5, 2.0]
```